# Symfony Class Not Found Exception in Laravel Auditing (5)

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

I want to integrate auditing into my app. I've followed all the steps to install laravel auditing with Laravel in the laravel auditing docs

But whenever I try to run `php artisan auditing:install`, I get this error and I have no idea why:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     There are no commands defined in the "auditing" namespace.

Is there something not in the documentation? What step am I missing?

**EDIT**

This is what my cmd prompt looks like
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C24M.png)

**EDIT**
This is also the config/app.php file 
[Please Click here to see config/app.php screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjQAn.png)

Comment: Did you add the service provider in your `config/app.php`?

Comment: Yes. And it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show your `config/app.php` file? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.3. I just added the config/app.php file to a new edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that may come across this issue --

If you are running valet/etc., it may be necessary to clear the cache/config, as follows:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:clear
```

Not sure which of the above helped, but cleared both and was able to use auditing:install.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the service provider in config/app.php  as suggested by patricus, if that does not solve, type this command in the cli,

```
composer dump-autoload
```

From the topmost Google [reference](http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/),

composer dump-autoload won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem